# How to add loader to angular material Filtering

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am using angular material table for displaying data in table format.
The filtering code for search data is

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

The filtering takes 6-7 seconds to retrieve data because of large data set.
Is there any way to add loader to this.

Comment: if that takes so long consider using web worker but in smaller scale you maybe be able to run it in async script but that will probably block user interface

Answer (score 0):

Please try `@matheo/datasource` as it supports a loading spinner  while the data is loaded, and also timeout messages. I'm planning the addition of some features to support different use cases, like a retry attempt after timeout.

For a working demo and further information, please check:
https://medium.com/@matheo/reactive-datasource-for-angular-1d869b0155f6